# area 2d in Godot 4.1.1 C# giving me an error

Tags: c#, godot4

I'm new to Godot and C#
I'm making a top down rpg and I have a area 2d with a script attached as a child of the background sprite. when the player enters the area2d and presses "ui_accept" the game will show a short description message of the thing that the player is touching(using area 2d)
there aren't many Godot C# tutorials to go off of but I used some older tutorials I found.
I'm using Godot 4.1.1
ill add more code to it but I want to resolve the errors first

```
   using Godot;
   using System;

   public partial class Area2D : Godot.Area2D
   {
    public override void _Ready(){
        Area2D area2d = this.GetNode<Area2D>("Area2D");
        area2d.Connect("body_enter",this,"_on_Area2D_body_enter");


    
    }
    


        private void _on_Area2D_body_enter(object body){
        GD.Print("text");
    }
    }
```

my signal is connected in the editor and I get these errors
Area2D.cs(8,37): Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Area2D' to 'Godot.Callable'
Area2D.cs(8,42): Argument 3: cannot convert from 'string' to 'uint'
I've been trying to resolve this and I don't know how so I hope someone on here can help!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if im understanding, you only have one Area2D, with this script attached? But the code makes me think you have a nested Area2D since you are getting the node in the Ready method, and the receiver method is also named like the signal is coming from a child.

In any case, if you connected the signal in the editor, you don't need to connect it in the Ready function, but often you definitely will need to connect signals through code, so the problem in your code is the 2nd argument which should be a callable, and the 3rd argument is the flags which is something more advanced and i'm not familiarized with honestly, but I doubt you will need to use that in most use cases.
Also you'd rather reference stuff like signal names or property names instead of hardcoding them, to avoid typos and therefore errors aswell.

Try this:

```
area2d.Connect(SignalName.BodyEntered, Callable.From((Node2D body) => _on_Area2D_body_enter(body)));
```

And when the signal you are connecting happens to belong to another class which the current script doesn't extend, you need to add the class before the signal name (like Area2D.SignalName.BodyEntered)

Also I encourage you to check the [docs](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/c_sharp/c_sharp_differences.html)

Most of the code examples and feature explanations are shown in both GDscript and C#